# Centering overflow:auto content inside DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a grid inside of a DIV viewport with overflow set to auto and want to add a zoom feature to it. The user should be able to zoom in/out but I want to keep the content center-aligned throughout the zoom process.

When zooming, the overflowing content on the horizontal axis is centered and, when scrolled left and right, I can see all 8 grid boxes on that axis - this is perfect. However, for some strange reason, the overflowing content on the Y axis is not centering when zoomed and the uppermost part of the grid disappears out of the viewport and annoyingly can't be seen or scrolled to.

When you zoom in, pay attention to how the horizontal scrollbar remains centered and that you can scroll left and right and see all 8 boxes but the vertical axis doesn't work the same way.

I welcome your suggestions and/or a solution. Thanks.

```js
$(function() {
  var $container = $('.container');
  var current_zoom = 1;
  var current_cell_size = 20;
  var cells_x = 8;
  var cells_y = 8;
  var grid_size_x = cells_x * current_cell_size;
  var grid_size_y = cells_y * current_cell_size;
  var $grid = $('<div />').addClass('grid').css({
    'width': grid_size_x,
    'height': grid_size_y
  });

  for (var x = 0; x < cells_y; x++) {
    var $row = $('<div />').addClass('row');
    for (var y = 0; y < cells_x; y++) {
      var $cell = $('<div />').addClass('cell').css({
        'width': current_cell_size,
        'height': current_cell_size
      });
      $row.append($cell);
    }
    $grid.append($row);
  }

  $container.append($grid);

  center_viewport();

  // ----- EVENTS

  $('.zoom-in-btn').click(zoom_in);
  $('.zoom-out-btn').click(zoom_out);

  // ----- FUNCTIONS

  function center_viewport() {
    $container.scrollLeft((grid_size_x - $container.width()) / 2);
    $container.scrollTop((grid_size_y - $container.height()) / 2);
  }

  function zoom_in() {
    current_cell_size = current_cell_size + 10;
    grid_size_x = cells_x * current_cell_size;
    grid_size_y = cells_y * current_cell_size;
    $grid.css({
      'width': grid_size_x,
      'height': grid_size_y
    }).find('.cell').css({
      'width': current_cell_size,
      'height': current_cell_size
    });
    center_viewport();
  }

  function zoom_out() {
    current_cell_size = current_cell_size - 10;
    grid_size_x = cells_x * current_cell_size;
    grid_size_y = cells_y * current_cell_size;
    $grid.css({
      'width': grid_size_x,
      'height': grid_size_y
    }).find('.cell').css({
      'width': current_cell_size,
      'height': current_cell_size
    });
    center_viewport();
  }

});
```

```css
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html .container,
body .container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 30px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: solid 1px #000;
}

html .container .grid,
body .container .grid {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

html .container .grid .row,
body .container .grid .row {
  display: flex;
}

html .container .grid .row:nth-child(odd) .cell:nth-child(odd),
body .container .grid .row:nth-child(odd) .cell:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #EEE;
}

html .container .grid .row:nth-child(even) .cell:nth-child(even),
body .container .grid .row:nth-child(even) .cell:nth-child(even) {
  background: #EEE;
}

html .container .zoom-btns,
body .container .zoom-btns {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  right: 50px;
  bottom: 50px;
}

html .container .zoom-btns button,
body .container .zoom-btns button {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="zoom-btns">
    <button class="zoom-in-btn">Zoom In</button>
    <button class="zoom-out-btn">Zoom Out</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Demo Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/5auwx8m2/7/).

Answer (score 0):

I think that instead of using `width`/`height` CSS properties to zoom, you should consider using `transform` and `transform-origin` properties. You can use the `scale` value of `transform` to zoom, then assign the coordinates of the center of the item as the `transform-origin` value.

- [CSS Transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform)
- [CSS Transform Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin)

Comment: Thanks. I have tried this already and got the same result. This was why I switched back to adjusting the width and height.